# Transition doesn't start when the mouse go on the area

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hover, transition

I'm creating a website, but I have a problem in transitions (my css and my html)

```css
.part1   {
 background-image:url(https://zupimages.net/up/18/14/49pg.jpg);
 background-attachment:fixed;
 position:relative;
 top:185px;
 font-family:Yu Gothic UI Light;
 font-size:110%;
 width:100%;
 height:500px;
 text-align:right;
 padding-right:5%;
 padding-left:50%;
 vertical-align:center;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-radius:30;
 -webkit-border-radius:30;
 -moz-border-radius:30;
 -o-border-radius:30;
 -ms-border-radius:30;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s ease-in-out; 
  -o-transition: -o-transform 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:font-size 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition:font-size 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  -o-transition:font-size 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition:font-size 0.5s ease-in-out;

}
.part1:hover  {

 font-size:130%;
 -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #888;  
 -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #888;  
 box-shadow:4px 4px 6px #888;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.5s, border 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); 
 -moz-transform: scale(1.05); 
 -o-transform: scale(1.05); 
 transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div class="part1">
<p>Nous créons des sites internet pour vous, rapidement et facilement. Pour <span class="blogs">une utilisation personnelle (blogs)</span> ou <span class="official">professionnelle (site officiel de l’entreprise avec un magasin en ligne)</span>, nous vous proposons des services.</p>
</div>
```

Why the transition doesn't start when the mouse go on the area "part1" ? And why the radius doesn't work in Chrome, but work in Edge !

Answer (score 0):

For the radius, you forgot to add the px unit after the border-radius. Here is the right code:

```
.part1          {
    background-image:url(https://zupimages.net/up/18/14/49pg.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    position:relative;
    top:185px;
    font-family:Yu Gothic UI Light;
    font-size:110%;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:5%;
    padding-left:50%;
    vertical-align:center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius:30px;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px;
    -moz-border-radius:30px;
    -o-border-radius:30px;
    -ms-border-radius:30px;
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out; 
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s ease-in-out; 
     -o-transition: -o-transform 2s ease-in-out;
     transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition:font-size 0.5s ease-in-out; 
     -moz-transition:font-size 0.5s ease-in-out; 
     -o-transition:font-size 0.5s ease-in-out;
     transition:font-size 0.5s ease-in-out;

}
.part1:hover        {

    font-size:130%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #888;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #888;  
    box-shadow:4px 4px 6px #888;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.5s, border 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05); 
    -o-transform: scale(1.05); 
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
```